# com.sun.net.httpserver not supported in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web

I am trying to deploy a web application already running in my local server to GAE.The thing is that i cannot overcome these errors:

com.sun.net.httpserver.
HttpExchange is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

java.net.InetSocketAddress is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpContext is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

These classes are important because get the server response/request handler running but it seems that these packages are not supported in GAE.There is the solution of servlets but i am not sure how they could replace the classes of this package.Any idea or alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the AppEngine [Java servlet environment documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime).

AppEngine itself provides the server; your application isn't supposed to try to provide that. All you provide is the servlets (using the classes from `javax.servlet.http`).